# Inner Join Looping thru

Tags: php, mysql

I have created an inner join between 2 Databases as shown below

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT gs.gs_users.id,gs.gs_user_objects.user_id, gs.gs_user_objects.imei, gs.gs_objects.imei, gs.gs_objects.lat, gs.gs_objects.lng,
gs.gs_objects.dt_server, gs.gs_objects.name, gs.gs_objects.odometer, dispatch.tablet_dispatch.client_id, 
dispatch.tablet_dispatch.destination, dispatch.tablet_dispatch.reg, dispatch.tablet_dispatch.d_name
FROM gs.gs_users
INNER JOIN dispatch.tablet_dispatch ON gs.gs_users.id = dispatch.tablet_dispatch.client_id
INNER JOIN gs.gs_user_objects ON gs.gs_users.id = gs.gs_user_objects.user_id
INNER JOIN gs.gs_objects ON gs.gs_user_objects.imei = gs.gs_objects.imei
WHERE dispatch.tablet_dispatch.client_id = '299' ");
?>
                      <?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                <td><a href="#!"><? echo $rows['name']; ?></a></td>
                                                                                <td><? echo $rows['d_name']; ?></td>
                                                                                <td><? echo $rows['destination']; ?></td>
                                                                                <td><? echo $rows['lat']; ?>, <? echo $rows['lng']; ?></td>
                                                                                <td><? echo $rows['dt_server']; ?></td>
                                                                            </tr>

<?php } ?>
```

The inner join works and it is getting the correct information. The problem I have is it is looping thru and sending multiple of the same information to the PHP table.

I Have a DB dispatch.tablet_dispatch.reg and the reg information in there is only one per vehicle so I want to join that table with information found in the other DB using the ID as specified '299' the id is common in all tables and linking with data from gs.gs_objects.name

Reply:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried using Group by id ?

Comment: Although I grouped by registration but still worked thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to this problem:

```
group by id
```

Comment: I have one last problem maybe this could be included in you answer. dispatch.tablet_dispatch.client_id, 
dispatch.tablet_dispatch.destination, dispatch.tablet_dispatch.reg, dispatch.tablet_dispatch.d_name Is all the same now and although the reg differs and each reg has different driver.  Why would it not join the second database info with the first one?

Comment: I have added a Picture. Destination , reg and d_name all same and they should be different

Comment: if I GROUP BY dispatch.tablet_dispatch.reg then the lats and longs stay the same i presume grouping issues here on the two DB's?

Comment: You should group by an unique id, and you can "group by" more than one value.

Answer (score 0):

Try Group by in your query and it will be work. 
Ex. Group by id